# How do you use objects in an If statement?

Tags: java, object, if-statement, integer, traversal

Given the following code:

```
    private static class Node<T>
         {
          public Node<T> left;
          public Node<T> right;
          public T data;

          public Node(T data)
          {
           this.data = data;
          }
}

    public static void chart()
         {
             //creating new node objects

                 Node<Integer> BOB = new Node<Integer>(16);
             Node<Integer> Cat = new Node<Integer>(17);
             Node<Integer> Charlie = new Node<Integer>(1);

             find(Charlie,BOB,Cat);
         }
```

How do you use an object in an IF statement? e.g. I want to see if the n or n.data (an Integer when equal to 16) is equal to the object BOB(which has an integer of 16) as below:

```
public static void find(Node<?> n,Node<?> f,Node<?> g)
     {
             //I also tried if (n == f) and all other combinations
         if (n.data == f.data)//here is the problem 
         {
             System.out.println("Found" + f);
         }

         if (n != null)
         {
             find(n.getLeft(), g, g);
             System.out.print(n.data + " ");
             find(n.getRight(), g, g);
         }
     }
```

The result should be when n is equal to 16 it will be equal to the object BOB (as it is 16) and then execute the IF statement. Note. I am using Organisation_chart_Traversal.

Comment: What do you parameters `n`, `f` and `g` mean?  Shouldn't you be passing `f` to the subsequent calls of `find`?

Comment: the parameters n, f and g are the three objects I'm inputting into the method in which will be used as Integers. so Charlie = 1, BOB = 16, Cat = 1.

Comment: Yeah, but what do the mean? They aren't very descriptive so it's hard to determine what roles they play...

Comment: Why are you using `Node<?>` ?

Comment: at the moment they do not play any roles it is incomplete code. They have just been injected into the method at the moment. Assume f and g are not their.

Comment: Node<?> means multiple objects can be used once created and  the <?> can be assigned different names depending on how the method was called. For example, Node <BOB> and n is equal to 16 so Node <BOB> 16.

Comment: This question makes no sense.  Your comment says you have three inputs and two of them have the same data, but your program has three objects all with different data.  You have a comment on a line that says "here is the problem", but it looks like you're comparing two different integers no matter how you slice it, so there's no indication of what the problem is.  You refer to `getLeft` and `getRight` methods that you don't define, and you give us no clue how the `left` and `right` fields are set.

Comment: but that was just example of code to help you understand the type of question. The question lies in the IF statement.

Comment: Well, it doesn't help me understand at all.  I still have no idea what you are asking, or what the problem is.  Why are you sure the `if` statement is the problem?

Comment: @ajb it does make sense because the getLeft and GetRight has nothing to do with the question. Please refer to the commented lines.

Comment: I've been looking at the comments.  They don't tell me anything.  Please tell us what result the "problem" line is giving you, what `n` and `f` are at the point when the problem line is executed, what result you expect, and why you expect that result.

Comment: OK, now that I can run the code, the reason you are getting a `NullPointerException` on the line `if (n.data == f.data)` is that either `n` or `f` is null.  The question is not "how do you compare objects in an `if` statement".  The question is "where did your code screw up so that it was trying to retrieve data from a null object".  If you had given us sufficient information to start with, we could have saved a lot of time.

Comment: @ajb it's a learning progress, question has been answered as I was comparing null objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you will use only numeric data types, just use `Number` class instead of `<T>`, In another cases, you need to use implements `Comparable<T>`

```
class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<T>
{
   Node<T> left;
   Node<T> right;
   T data;

   Node(T data) { /*...*/ }

   @Override
   public int compareTo(T d) {
       return data.compareTo(d);
   } 
}
```

When you will compare Nodes, use following expression `if(n1.compareTo(n2) == 0)`

1. 0 - objects is equel
2. 1 - the first object is greater than object second
3. -1 - the first object is less, than object second

Answer (score -2):

**Note**: You need to make sure that `n`, `n.data` and `f` are not null before this code.

Instead of using `==` you can use `equals` method for value other then the range of -128..127.

As suggested by `@ajb`: When you have Integer objects whose values are in the range -128..127, == and .equals give you the same result.

```
public static void find(Node<?> n,Node<?> f,Node<?> g) {
    if (n != null && f != null && n.data != null) { 
        if (n.data.equals(f.data)) {
            System.out.println("Found" + f); // I think you want to print f.data
        }
    }
    if (n != null) {
        find(n.getLeft(), f, g);
        System.out.print(n.data + " ");
        find(n.getRight(), f, g);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it doesn't work this exception appears:                                           at Organisation_Chart_Traversal.find(Organisation_Chart_Traversal.java:207)

Comment: Note that this will not make a difference in the OP's example.  When you have `Integer` objects whose values are in the range -128..127, `==` and `.equals` give you the same result.

Comment: @ZSoftwareundergraduate Do you think we are all mind readers that we know what `Organisation_Chart_Traversal` is?

Comment: @ZSoftwareundergraduate, please provide full stacktrace

Comment: Can you wrap your code of `chart()` in `try catch block` and print `e.printStackTrace()` in catch block. And post full stack trace.

Comment: @NamanGala answer was correct but obviously as said, only works when n.data is not null.

Comment: So you can handle null part.

Comment: No, just a statement. That you can handle the null part before this code execute.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Organisation_Chart_Traversal.find(Organisation_Chart_Traversal.java:201)
 at Organisation_Chart_Traversal.find(Organisation_Chart_Traversal.java:206)
 at Organisation_Chart_Traversal.find(Organisation_Chart_Traversal.java:206)
 at Organisation_Chart_Traversal.find(Organisation_Chart_Traversal.java:206)
 at Organisation_Chart_Traversal.find(Organisation_Chart_Traversal.java:206)
 at Organisation_Chart_Traversal.chart(Organisation_Chart_Traversal.java:193)

Comment: woops,with try catch:
Found16--
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Organisation_Chart_Traversal.find(Organisation_Chart_Traversal.java:208)
at Organisation_Chart_Traversal.find(Organisation_Chart_Traversal.java:213)
 at Organisation_Chart_Traversal.find(Organisation_Chart_Traversal.java:213)
 at Organisation_Chart_Traversal.find(Organisation_Chart_Traversal.java:213)
 at Organisation_Chart_Traversal.find(Organisation_Chart_Traversal.java:213)
 at Organisation_Chart_Traversal.chart(Organisation_Chart_Traversal.java:200)
 at Organisation_Chart_Traversal.main(Organisation_Chart_Traversal.java:166)

Comment: You need to make sure that `n`, `n.data` and `f` are not null. You can add a null check. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @ZSoftwareundergraduate, did your problem get solve?